# Restoring an intuitionism answer

Tags: support, specific-answer

There was this very fine answer by @Jobermark justifying and explaining intuitionism.
I think it was this one:
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/64039/37256
though I'm not sure since the question seems deleted. 
I wanted to refer it [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/65846/37256)

1. Can someone with the reputation confirm this?
2. If so how may we restore this answer?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are referring to [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/64335/17209). It was deleted by jobermark himself, seemingly after a comment by the question owner implied that it was not exactly what he was looking for.

Thus, since the owner himself deleted the answer, only he can/should decide to undelete his intellectual property.

Comment: Not quibbling with "should," but re: "can," is it not the case that others (with sufficient reputation) can vote to undelete?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Technically correct, that's why I chose the can/should formulation. We could undelete it, but it *should* be his decision (we are morally bound by his decision to have his intellectual property deleted) and thus only he can *legitimately* choose to do so.

Comment: Oh I entirely agree (and I'm not wild about that option existing), I just wanted to double-check my technical understanding (I know how it works on MSE/MO but wasn't sure it was the same here).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I believe that if a user deletes their own answer only mods can undelete it. While in general users' wishes to have their answers be deleted should be respected, if a user deletes lots of posts in a rage quit, their posts should all be restored. That's the one exception.

Comment: @curiousdannii On MSE at least I can vote to undelete, and I'm not a mod. But maybe here it's different?

Comment: @Noah I think there are different rules based on who deleted the post. If it's the community then the community can undelete. If the user I think only them or a mod. Could be wrong.

Comment: I've put a comment here https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/65832/37256.  Maybe good to wait a bit?